# Matlab two complex number multiplication

Tags: matlab

(   0.0037 -22.2145i ) / ( 1.2168e+002 -1.2166e+002i )=   0.0913 - 0.0913i

According to calculators on web, division of these two values must be a different value. But MATLAB calculates different (the result of matlab calculation is given on top). the code part which calculates is like:

```
disp(((MagPlusOne)*(kiz)));
disp((Magnetic*kizPlusOne));
disp(((MagPlusOne*kiz)/(Magnetic*kizPlusOne)));
```

Comment: So what value do you expect then?

Comment: -5.55119057342243-5.55454954346864i - according to https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/complex-number-calculator.html

Comment: I get the same result you obtained with Matlab with Python and with [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28+0.0037+-22.2145i+%29+%2F+%28+1.2168e%2B002+-1.2166e%2B002i+%29). I thrust the 3 of those much more than some random website implemented in Flash.

Comment: not a programming question....

Comment: May be not a programming question but it is a problem that i can not solve. anyway, thanks @JasonS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matlab is correct.  The issue is that the tool you're comparing Matlab's result to does not parse scientific notation.  Entering your equation, the online tool interprets it as

```
(0.0037- 22.2145i)/( 1.2168*e + 2  - (1.2166*e + 2i))
```

which is clearly a different number.

If the scientific notation is replace with fixed-decimals

```
( 0.0037 -22.2145i ) / ( 121.68 - 121.66i ),
```

the tool produces that desired result `0.0913-0.09123i`.